# Приоритет вывода значений в плагине WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю плагин, который возвращает таблицу с данными. Примерный код:

```
    function text_print(){
  $data = some_data();
  echo "
      <table >
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th ></th>
          <th ></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td > $data </td>
          <td ></td>
          <td ></td>
          <td ></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  ";
  }
function data(){
return "something text jnjnm ";
}
```

В php все работает как нужно - данные выводит в ичейке таблицы. После вставки функции в плагин и запуск на WordPress - текст выводит над таблицей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение

```
function text_print(){
  $data = data();
  return "
      <table >
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th ></th>
          <th ></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td >".$data."</td>
          <td ></td>
          <td ></td>
          <td ></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  ";
  }
function data(){
return "something text jnjnm ";
}
```

Во всех функциях возвращать значения используя return тогда данные(переменные, функции) не будет выводить выше всего.